# Conversion from htaccess to rewrite issue

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, url-rewriting

I have moved site from apache to nginx and I have got some issue with nginx.

htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+[^/])/(.*[^/])/?$ index.php?p=$1&subp=$2&subsubp=$3 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+[^/])/?$ index.php?p=$1&subp=$2 [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])/?$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA,L]
Options -Indexes
```

And using converter to nginx:

```
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$ {
} 
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$ {
} 
location ~ \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|bmp|ttf|php|php5|html|htm|gif)$ {
} 
autoindex off; 
location / {
rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+[^/])/(.*[^/])/?$ /index.php?p=$1&subp=$2&subsubp=$3 break;
rewrite ^/(.+)/(.+[^/])/?$ /index.php?p=$1&subp=$2 break; 
rewrite ^/(.*[^/])/?$ /index.php?p=$1 break; 
}
```

**I think that, can work when we are not talking about subdomain.**

Yes - my site is in subdomain called /mysub/

So to enter my website I use mysub.domain.com or domain.com/mysub/ 
(where the first is this:)

```
if ($http_host = "mysub.domain.com") {
    rewrite ^(?!/\b(mysub|stats|error)\b)/(.*)$ /mysub/$2 ;
}
```

Question:

**How to link these rules into one ?**